# Magento 2.3.3 Possible Issues

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.3

Magento just released a new version 2.3.3 with 170 core bugs fixes, supported PHP 7.3 and PSD2 compliance for core payment methods

Has someone faced any issue in Magento 2.3.3?

Thanks

Comment: Does anyone know if the performance issues caused by MSI have been fixed https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22027 https://github.com/magento/inventory/issues/2496

Comment: I'm facing issue from 2.3.2 CE to 2.3.3 setup:upgrade stuck at Magento_GoogleShoppingAds.

Answer (score 1):

Action's arguments in UI components' XML that previously implement Zend\Stdlib\JsonSerializable no longer supports and should be changed to implementation of Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface. Also, rename jsonSerialize into toOptionArray and it should be fixed.
So if you have classes like

```
use Zend\Stdlib\JsonSerializable;

class Some implements JsonSerializable
{
    public function jsonSerialize() {
```

just change it to

```
use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

class Some implements JsonSerializable
{
    public function toOptionArray() {
```

Also, don't forget to update your requirejs's build.js bundles because some new js libs were added. And recheck PayPal front-end component on checkout sometimes there an issue with it (it disabled).

Answer (score 0):

1. temando.CRITICAL: "accountId" is required. Enter and try again 
   This issue due to temando_shipping module. You can disable it first
2. Store email addresses will only accept 1 in bcc
3. 500 error when editing previously created product.

Comment: Update, it appears temando is required after disabling we could not edit products so after re-enabling and removing the second bcc  everything works fine. The bcc causes causes new order emails to be not sent if the comma separation is , space so bcc emailaddress1@somewhere, emailaddress2@somewhere does not work and causes new order emails to be not sent.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to get CDN to work with Magento 2.3.3, but not sure if that is a config problem or something to do with the platform. I am following the steps from online guides (they are all the same), but it does not seem to work properly with HTML files and fonts :(

[CORS error - HTML and fonts not working properly with CloudFront CDN](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/295620/cors-error-html-and-fonts-not-working-properly-with-cloudfront-cdn)

Answer (score 0):

One issue with 2.3.3 is category images get removed when you save a category.
There is a fix on github: https://github.com/FutureActivities/Magento-Fix-Category-Images

I have had to apply this patch twice on two 2.3.3 installations so it seems like a common issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am having issue with magento 2.3.3 and 2.3.4 versions. I am using Grouped product structure. On product page if I choose one of the related product then it start showing starting at: price on top of the grouped products.
Can anyone help in that please?
Thanks

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/173576)

Comment: created new question. thanks